# Delete all objects in S3 bucket except one which comes last in lexicographical order group by a prefix

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, distributed-filesystem

Consider an S3 bucket with objects with keys like:

```
abc_1_epoch1.ext
abc_1_epoch2.ext
abc_2_epoch1.ext
xyz_1_epcoh1.ext
```

When i group by keys with prefix, then due to epoch it forms a lexicographical order. I want to delete all objects except the one which comes last in lexicographical order. So, the expected output in the bucket after cleanup task is:

```
abc_1_epoch2.ext
abc_2_epoch1.ext
xyz_1_epoch1.ext
```

As you can see grouping keys are abc_1, abc_2 and xyz_1. Point to note is that i have multi-million such objects in the bucket and hence I want a scalable solution.

Comment: Fetching a list of millions of objects can be onerous so look at S3 Inventory, assuming you can tolerate results being a few hours old. Retrieve the inventory report, parse it, and produce your list of objects to delete.

Comment: Also, consider a lifecycle rule to remove old objects, if a simple object-created check applies to the objects here.

Comment: On the lifecycle option, see Why should I use object tags? at [Simplify your data lifecycle by using object tags with Amazon S3 Lifecycle](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/simplify-your-data-lifecycle-by-using-object-tags-with-amazon-s3-lifecycle/).